# how to uninstall compiled php

Tags: php, linux, makefile

I installed php with make install. Now I go to the directory I compiled my php and do `make uninstall`. It throws this error `make: *** No rule to make target 'uninstall'. stop.`.

What is going on?

Centos6

PHP 5

Comment: Well the error message is pretty self-saying, isn't it? Also in cent-os there is normally a package available to install or uninstall php. you can also create your own packages. Also I think this forum discussion might be insightful: [Source uninstall with 'make uninstall' HOWTO!](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/source-uninstall-with-make-uninstall-howto-230225/) - it explains why make uninstall is not available always.

Comment: gee, this is an extremely pertinent question for any PHP **programmer** or even a web programmer. it's the most basic thing you do for any development: install and uninstall runtime. yet, this is closed!?? i wish stack overflow would award less points for banding together to close questions - it has become too aggressive. or, award a huge number of points to anybody willing to make "commomn-sense exceptions" to rigid definitions.

Comment: This question alone has seen over 1001 views. We could have had some really good input from the community here if it had not been closed. I nominate this question for a re-opening.

Comment: Seconding the reopening.

Comment: Voting for reopen, because it's about "software tools commonly used by programmers".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If there is no 'uninstall' target, there isn't any automated way to uninstall and remove files.

If by luck you built your php in a 100% dedicated directory (/opt/your/php for example) then uninstalling may be as simple as removing this dedicated directory, as everything generated at build/compile time will be contained inside this directory.

Comment: You can also determine which day it was installed, find files last modified at that time, and delete those. For example, if you installed php on March 6, 2014 and compiled it to /usr/local, run 

find /usr/local -type f -newermt '2014-03-06' to verify the files, then add -delete to that command to actually delete the files.

Comment: @roberttstephens: Very nicely executed out of the box thinking.

Comment: `if pushd '/usr/local'; for subDir in '.' 'bin' 'lib' 'include'; if pushd "$subDir"; find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \( -iname 'php*' -o -iname 'phar*' \) -a -printf '%f\n'; popd; end; end; popd; end`.  Can use `-delete` and/or `-exec rm -rf '{}' \+` when find is run with `sudo` for system locations.